Tug of war between observers in frames with different rate of time
You have a very dense hollow sphere of matter. Observer A is inside the sphere inside a rocket. Observer B is in an identical rocket outside the sphere where the ring's gravity is negligible. They are then both inertial observers and are stationary relative to each other, but A's clock ticks slower. They have a rope attached to both rockets and turn on their identical jets in opposite direction.
a) Who wins the tug of war?
b) Assuming A's clock ticks at half the rate of B's clock and the rope is "solid" to allow both push and pull, how much does A measure that he has moved after B moves 1 meter and stops?
Simplifications:
The rope has negligible mass.
I know B can't be too close to the sphere due to gravity but if possible let's make the proper distance between the observers as small as possible to avoid unnecessary complexities due to the speed of sound of the rope, etc.

You can have $B$ be close and just add another mass--basically put him at Lagrange point so the gravity is not just small, but is $0$. And what is "the ring"? Also, thought experiment ropes are limited by Born Rigidity, and can have up to $c$ propagation (iirc).

I will address only question (a). Assuming sufficient distance that the gravitational pull on B is negligible (and, as stated in the question, that the gravitational pull on the rope is negligible), the distant observer B will win. Intuitively this should already be clear: the "fast" observer beats the "slow" (gravitationally time dilated) observer.
To understand why this is correct, it is helpful to consider a modified version of the problem. Instead of pulling a rope, imagine that there is an object (maybe a bomb) in space between the two observers, and each is using a laser to try to push that object toward the other observer. The two observers are equipped with identical lasers.
Coming from deep in a gravitational well, the photons from observer A's laser are gravitationally redshifted, so they have less energy and momentum when they strike the object, compared to the photons from observer B's laser. Thus, observer B will win this pushing contest. Returning to the rope scenario, you can imagine a similar story with the acoustic impulses the carry each observer's pull through through the rope. The pull from observer A is redshifted, making it weaker.

-1. How the force is transmitted along the rope (and hence who would win the tug of war) is strongly dependent on the matter model for the rope and is determined by equation $\nabla_a T^{ab}=0$. So your considered model of photonic strut $\mu=+F$ would be different from e.g. relativistic string $\mu=-F$ where there would be a draw.

@A.V.S. Which physical quantities are you referring to with $\mu$ and $F$?

Linear energy density and force. Basically, components of $T^a{}_b$ integrated over rope cross section.

At least it should be save to say that the slower observer can't win, so there is at least a draw, or the faster observer wins. I think the point of the question is if forces are equal and opposite under Einstein just as they were under Newton, which due to time dilation they are not.

@Yukterez:  slower observer can't win Why would you think that? My point is that Sten chose arbitrary matter model made argument about forces for that model and declared a win based on forces alone. But tug of war is not about forces ...

How the force changes along the rope depends not just on the relative redshift but also on the specific matter model for the rope.
The equation that governs forces along the rope stems from relativistic conservation of energy-momentum $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$. In curved spacetime this equation ensures that force along the rope (a spatial component of this equation) would  also depend on mass density of that rope. This means that “simplification” of negligible mass of the rope in strongly relativistic situations is untenable for any realistic matter model of the rope (and relative redshift of 2 suggested in OP makes the situation strongly relativistic). And it is precisely the weight of the rope and also additional weight of pressures/stresses in that rope that causes changes of tension/compression forces along the rope, there is no other law describing the redshift of force.
By “realistic matter model” we meant the one satisfying reasonable energy conditions. For example if the linear energy-density of the rope (in its rest frame) is $\mu$ and its tension is $T$ then energy conditions demand (null, weak and dominant all agree in this case) that $$\mu\ge T,\tag{*}$$
in units with $c=1$.
For a simplified case of static rope we have  the following equation (taken from Brown, 2012, eq. 5):
$$\frac{ dT}{dr} + \frac1χ \frac{dχ}{dr} T = \frac1χ \frac{dχ}{dr} μ ,\tag{**}$$
where $χ$ is the lapse function (time rate relative to infinity at a given position), and all quantities depend on radial coordinate only. Let us assume that at the start of tug of war game both observers are at rest and heavy enough that dynamics of the rope can be considered quasistatic and thus adequately described by (**).
The special case $\mu=T=\mathrm{const}>0$  corresponds to relativistic string model and “ropes” that satisfy this equation include electric field lines, cosmic strings and fundamental strings of string theory. For this case and this case only there is no “redshift of the force”, the weights of linear density and tension cancel each other so that tension remains constant along the length of the rope and  in this special case the tug of war would be a draw, neither rocket would move.
When (*) becomes strict inequality the tension would be growing with radial coordinate ($dT/dr>0$) to compensate for the weight of the rope. This means that observer A (inside the shell)  would win the tug of war in the sense that observer B would be moving toward the shell faster than observer A. This is not surprising even in Newtonian gravity: the tension at the lower end of the rope is smaller than at the higher end. In Newtonian gravity the difference is precisely the weight of the rope. In GR there is also a relativistic effect: tension $T$ (negative pressure) reduces the weight but energy conditions ensure that this reduction cannot overcome the full weight.
If the strength of the rope comes from chemical bonds then the maximum tension to linear density ratio achievable for such a material would be quite small by relativistic standards: even high-performance materials such as carbon nanotubes can sustain no more than  $10^{-8} \mu $ tension.
If instead of tension we have a compression force (which corresponds to $T<0$) then the observer inside the shell would feel the full weight of the rod (it cannot be called a rope anymore). Note, that the game is different here: we have pushing instead of pulling. Again nothing unexpected from the viewpoint of Newtonian gravity: the force at the bottom of compression member is larger than the force at the top. Plus again a relativistic effect: positive compression force add to the weight of mass-energy.
To summarize: For (quasi)static ropes/rods in static gravitational fields changes of tension/compression forces along the rope/rod are just due to the weights of mass-energy and stresses along the rope.
